# Lost button selections after scrolling tacbleview

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a tableview that uses re-useable cells. Each cell has a label and a stack view that contains 5 buttons. The issue is since the cells are reusable once i scroll, the selections of the buttons are lost. What is the best way to ensure that button selections are not lost once a user scrolls.

The issue is not the capturing of button selection. Only the UI part where after i scroll, the image selected is not the one that is displayed, however the value is already recorded.

Comment: Take one array to maintain your selection.

Comment: Please post some code what have you tried.

Answer (score 0):

As the cells are reusable you should save button state in Dictionary and then set state in *cellForRow*

It's should looks like:

```
struct ButtonState {
   var firstButtonSelected = false
   var secondButtonSelected = false
}

var buttonStates = Dictionary<Int, ButtonState>()


// save state in buttonStates 

func saveState(cellIndex: Int, buttonIndex: Int, state: Bool) {
   var buttonState = buttonStates[cellIndex]
   if buttonState == nil {
      buttonState = ButtonState()
   }
   if buttonIndex == 0 {
      buttonState.firstButtonSelected = state
   } else if buttonIndex == 0 {
      buttonState.secondButtonSelected = state
   }
}


//set states in cell buttons

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   if let buttonState = buttonStates[cellIndex] {
       cell.firstButton.selected = buttonState.firstButtonSelected
   }
}
```

This peace of code is not so clear but I tried to explain my idea.